# Getting started with shared memory on PyCUDA

Tags: python, cuda, gpgpu, pycuda, pyopencl

I'm trying to understand shared memory by playing with the following code:

```
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.tools
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

src='''
__global__ void reduce0(float *g_idata, float *g_odata) {
extern __shared__ float sdata[];
// each thread loads one element from global to shared mem
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

sdata[tid] = g_idata[i];
__syncthreads();
// do reduction in shared mem
for(unsigned int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *= 2) {
   if (tid % (2*s) == 0) {
      sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
   }
__syncthreads();
}
// write result for this block to global mem
if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
'''

mod = SourceModule(src)
reduce0=mod.get_function('reduce0')

a = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)

dest = numpy.zeros_like(a)
reduce0(drv.In(a),drv.Out(dest),block=(400,1,1))
```

I can't see anything obviously wrong with this, but I keep getting synchronization errors and it doesn't run.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are not specifying a shared memory size to the kernel launch.

Comment: Turns out that extern __shared__ float sdata[]; is the way the nvcc compiler needs it.

Comment: Yes, but when a kernel uses dynamically allocated shared memory, you have to pass the shared memory allocation size in bytes as a kernel launch argument. The code you posted does not do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you specify

```
extern __shared__ float sdata[];
```

you are telling the compiler that the caller will provide the shared memory.  In PyCUDA, that is done by specifying `shared=nnnn` on the line that calls the CUDA function.  In your case, something like:

```
reduce0(drv.In(a),drv.Out(dest),block=(400,1,1),shared=4*400)
```

Alternately, you can drop the extern keyword, and specify the shared memory directly:

```
__shared__ float sdata[400];
```

Comment: Actually, I had to both drop the extern keyword and used the `shared=` argument to get it to work.

Comment: @reckoner When not using the extern word, the defined memory is probably being used from the hard limit of 48 kB. The shared argument can be set to zero. 

When the extern is used, such memory is used as so called dynamic shared memory which is used to access more than 48 kB on newer architectures and the shared argument is needed to make this work.