# PyCUDA LogicError: cuModuleLoadDataEx failed: an illegal memory access was encountered

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I am trying to parallelize the bitonic sort with pycuda. For this I use SourceModule and the C code of the parallel bitonic sort. For the memory copies management I use InOut of the pycuda.driver that simplify some of the memory transfers

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
from pycuda import gpuarray
import numpy as np
from time import time

ker = SourceModule(
    """
    __device__ void swap(int & a, int & b){
        int tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }

    __global__ void bitonicSort(int * values, int N){
        extern __shared__ int shared[];
        int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
        // Copy input to shared mem.
        shared[tid] = values[tid];
        __syncthreads();
        // Parallel bitonic sort.
        for (int k = 2; k <= N; k *= 2){
            // Bitonic merge:
            for (int j = k / 2; j>0; j /= 2){
                int ixj = tid ^ j;
                if (ixj > tid){
                    if ((tid & k) == 0){
                        //Sort ascending
                        if (shared[tid] > shared[ixj]){
                            swap(shared[tid], shared[ixj]);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        //Sort descending
                        if (shared[tid] < shared[ixj]){
                            swap(shared[tid], shared[ixj]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                __syncthreads();
            }
        }
        values[tid] = shared[tid];
    }
    """
)

N = 8 #lenght of A
A = np.int32(np.random.randint(1, 20, N)) #random numbers in A
BLOCK_SIZE = 256
NUM_BLOCKS = (N + BLOCK_SIZE-1)//BLOCK_SIZE
bitonicSort = ker.get_function("bitonicSort")
t1 = time()
bitonicSort(drv.InOut(A), np.int32(N), block=(BLOCK_SIZE,1,1), grid=(NUM_BLOCKS,1), shared=4*N)
t2 = time()
print("Execution Time {0}".format(t2 - t1))
print(A)
```

As in the kernel I use `extern __shared__`, in pycuda I use the shared parameter with the respective 4*N. Also try using `__shared__ int shared[N]` in the kernel but it doesn't work either (check here: [Getting started with shared memory on PyCUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696860/getting-started-with-shared-memory-on-pycuda))

Running in Google Collab I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycuda/compiler.py in __init__(self, source, nvcc, options, keep, no_extern_c, arch, code, cache_dir, include_dirs)
    292 
    293         from pycuda.driver import module_from_buffer
--> 294         self.module = module_from_buffer(cubin)
    295 
    296         self._bind_module()

LogicError: cuModuleLoadDataEx failed: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

Does anyone know what could be generating this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device code isn't accounting for the sizes of your arrays correctly.

You are launching 256 threads in a single block. That means that you will have 256 threads, with `tid` numbered 0..255, trying to execute each line of code. For example, in this case:

```
shared[tid] = values[tid];
```

You will have, for example, one thread trying to do `shared[255] = values[255];`

Neither your `shared` nor `values` array are that large.  That is the reason for the illegal memory access error.

The simplest solution for this kind of trivial problem is to make your array sizes match your block size.

```
BLOCK_SIZE = N
```

According to my testing, that change clears up any errors and results in a properly sorted array.

It won't work for `N` greater than 1024, or multi-block usage, but your code would have to be modified for a multi-block sort, anyway.

If you still have trouble after making that change, I suggest restarting your python session or your colab session.

Comment: While your observation is correct, I don't think this is actually a runtime code problem, but rather a runtime build problem. Usually that sort of blow up inside the compiler infrastructure means that there are broken toolchain/incompatibilities between PyCUDA and the host toolkit

Comment: You are probably right.  I could not hypothesize a reason why that error would occur at module load time, so I conjectured that it was leftover from a previous run and was not being cleared out due to some interactive usage of python.  That is why I made the final comment in my answer.  I don't know why this error would occur at module load time, for a fresh run (it seems impossible).  With the change I suggested, I can at least assert that it runs correctly for me, and so if problems remain I don't believe they are with the code.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much. I have to modify the code to use multi-block sort, any hint?

Comment: to sort numbers on the GPU, I would use a library implementation.  If you want to write the code yourself (not recommended), there is a [CUDA sample code](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-sorting-networks) that does a multi-block bitonic sort.